# Initializing Input Fields with React-Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to initialize the input fields with the selected car data (Car Details Screen) when user clicks on a row in a `Flatlist` (List of Car Screen)

I get the following error

> _this2.props.updateCarForm is not a function

I am able to pass the car object as `params` to Car Details Screen

however, when I pass the 'car' object to the `_.each(...)` function, it will produce the above error when I click on the row to navigate me to the Car Details page

Any one with ideas how I can resolve this issue? tq

Car List Screen

```
class CarList extends React.Component {
goToCar = car => {
this.props.navigation.navigate("CarEdit", car);
};

<FlatList
        data={this.props.cars}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
              <Text>
                {item.model} - {item.country} - {item.capacity}
              </Text>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this.onRemoveCar(item.model)}
              >
                <Text>REMOVE</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.goToCar(item)}>
                <Text>EDIT</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          );
        }}
        keyExtractor={item => item.model}
/>
```

Car Edit Screen

```
class CarEdit extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const car = this.props.navigation.state.params;
    console.log("Car", this.car);
    _.each(car, (value, prop) => {
      this.props.updateCarForm({ prop, value });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you please add the code that you pass `updateCarForm` prop to `CarEdit ` component and the `updateCarForm` function?

Comment: be sure that the scoping is correct. That the "this" is pointing to the component and not the the .each function it self since you use lodash

Comment: Hi bennygenel, i have added the code. Thks for looking through :)

Comment: Hi Panagiotis, i tried using this.car but it cannot work. _.each(this.car, (value, prop) => {
      this.props.updateCarForm({ prop, value });
    });  any idea what other way i can bind the this to the right component? thks :)